# Logs when Kubernetes OpenID Connect authentication fails

Tags: kubernetes, openid-connect, keycloak

I have tried to set up Kubernetes 1.13 for OpenID Connect (OIDC) authentication as follows:

- installed Keycloak server
- added command line options `--oidc-issuer-url=https://my_keycloak/auth/realms/my_realm`, etc., to `kube-apiserver`
- stored id token at `users.user.auth-provider.config.client-id`, etc., in kubeconfig's `my_user`

From my reading of the documentation `kubectl` should now be able to access the cluster as `my_user`. However, `kubectl get nodes` says:

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

And `curl -k https://api_server:6443/api/v2/nodes --header "Authorization: Bearer $id_token"` says:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "reason": "Unauthorized",
  "code": 401
}
```

`kubectl logs $kube_apiserver -n kube-system`, `journalctl -u kubelet.service`, and Keycloak's stdout are all silent. So where can I see more logging information to discern where OIDC authentication may go wrong?

**UPDATE** Option [`--v`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22723) on both the client (`keyctl`) or the server (e.g. API server) help to some degree.

Comment: Do you have an `id-token:` in your kubeconfig, as [shown in their example output](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#option-1-oidc-authenticator)? Because if not, then kubelet was not able to actually perform the OIDC handshake. I can't tell if you grabbed the value from your `kubeconfig` in your example `curl` or what

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I have obtained the id token with a previous curl request to Keycloak's OIDC rest API, and checked its validity at jwt.io. So yes, my kubeconfig conforms to this example.

Comment: Hmm, that's a toughie then; what about `--oidc-issuer-url=` and `--oidc-username-claim=`? I haven't used jwt.io but it might allow you to inspect the claims that are inside your JWT

Comment: And, of course, do you have multiple apiservers in your cluster, and if so are they all successfully running with those flags?

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I've configured those flags in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`, so FWIK they should be picked up everywhere.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic, double-check that kubelet actually did restart your apiserver containers, as I have seen instances where kubelet did not notice the file changed, and only restarting kubelet cured it

Comment: You can also [set up a cluster using vagrant](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.8.2/docs/vagrant.md#vagrant-install) and test that your [OIDC settings](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.8.2/roles/kubernetes/master/defaults/main.yml#L103-L115) could possibly work in a little bit more of a laboratory setting

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Mine is (was) also a laboratory setting, so that's okay :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the `email` claim, Kubernetes requires your `email_verified` claim to be `true`. By default in Keycloak, this is set to `false`.

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/search?q=email_verified&unscoped_q=email_verified